# Login to web page that uses redirect

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to automate logging in and perform downloading load later on. There is a redirect on the page and once I am trying to access the page directly by Selenium web driver I am getting an error message from the page:

> Previous authentication session has expired. In order to proceed, you
>   have to sign in again.

I have found a link for redirect on the front page and accessing from selenium by this link but now I am getting an error message

```
var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("loginForm:username");
```

not found on the page.

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"#loginForm:username"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=78.0.3904.108)'

Where is the problem? Is it so that I should drop some "wait" until the page has been loaded command? I have added "wait" as you can see in my code (hopefully it is done correct) but still result is the same with the same error.

Here is my current code:

```
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace WebDriverTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Initialize the Chrome Driver
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                // Go to the home page
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://portal.vastuugroup.fi/api/general/external-redirects?lang=fi&amp;sp_route=/");

                // Get the page elements
                OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

                var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("loginForm:username");
                var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("loginForm:password");
                var loginButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='loginForm:loginButton']");

                // Type user name and password
                userNameField.SendKeys("user@email.com");
                userPasswordField.SendKeys("12345");

                // and click the login button
                loginButton.Click();

                // Extract the text and save it into result.txt
                // var result = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='case_login']/h3").Text;
                // File.WriteAllText("result.txt", result);

                // Take a screenshot and save it into screen.png
                driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"screen.png", OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have provided correct stacktrace because based on that you are failed to locate CSS element and in your code you are passing ID of element FindElementById("loginForm:username");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace WebDriverTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initialize the Chrome Driver
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                // Go to the home page
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://portal.vastuugroup.fi/api/general/external-redirects?lang=fi&amp;sp_route=/");
                   driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                // Get the page elements
                var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("loginForm:username");
                var userPasswordField = driver.FindElementById("loginForm:password");
                var loginButton = driver.FindElementById("loginForm:loginButton");

                // Type user name and password
                userNameField.SendKeys("username");
                userPasswordField.SendKeys("password");

                // and click the login button
                loginButton.Click();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but it gets stuck at the same stage with following error message `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#loginForm\:username"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)'`

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting this issue because we are not using css selector in the code. Try to create another class and then run your code again

Comment: Same result, I have tried with Firefox as well. This website seems to be prepared